# AS3 - Call a PHP script on my server to determine the URL of the SWF

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, url

I'm a flash game developer. I need to be able to determine the URL of the page that the SWF is embedded on, and I can't use ExternalInterface. The reason is that a lot of flash portals set allowScriptAccess="never". It's also quite common for flash portals to not actually host the SWF themselves, but embed the SWF on their page and have it loaded from someone else's server. I need a reliable way to determine the URL of the page that the SWF is embedded on, and I can use an external server.

I know this isn't possible using flash alone, but I believe it should be possible in combination with using an external server.

While searching, I came across a forum post that said "Figured it out: Server can get page adress (when browser request file server can read page adress) and return it as param to flash." Unfortunately, no further details were provided. That thread can be found here:

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=138370

I'm not even sure if PHP is what I'm looking for - I have little knowledge of web technologies outside of Flash. My questions are:

1. Is this actually possible?
2. If so, what should I use to do it? Is  PHP what I'm looking for? Something else?

**Update:**
My goal (however it can be achieved) is to get the URL that the SWF is being viewed on WITHOUT being dependent on any particular embed settings (so no ExternalInterface, or passing in a FlashVar). I won't have control over how and where the SWF is embedded. Exmaple, the SWF is hosted on somedomain.com/test.swf, and it's embedded on fungames.com/cool-game. I need to know that the URL is fungames.com/cool-game. Knowing where the actual SWF file is hosted is not useful information. If the full URL is not obtainable, the domain would be good enough.

**Update 2:**
I got setup with AMFPHP on my server, and I got it to return the HTTP_REFERER, but in my test case, it returned the URL of the SWF and not the URL of the page that the SWF is embedded on. Is there a different property I can look at?

Comment: Information about your goal may be helpful as there may be solutions outside of what you're trying to do in this question :)

Comment: Do you need the full URL or will just the domain be enough for you?

Comment: I've added two updates to clarify what I'm looking for, and what I've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the URL of a running SWF by using this:

```
var url:String = LoaderInfo(root.loaderInfo).url;
```

Comment: That will return the URL of the SWF, it will not return the URL of the page that the SWF is embedded on. I need to know the URL of the page that the SWF is embedded on.

Comment: Not sure thats possible without an ExternalInterface call. What is the use case?

Comment: The use case is the game spreads to thousands of different portals, and I have no control over how it's embedded. Therefore, I cannot use ExternalInterface because many portals have allowScriptAccess="false".

Answer (score 0):

your swf can call the php page on your server and reference the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` property

Comment: The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. **In short, it cannot really be trusted.** - php.net

Comment: True mate, just adding some information in case the OP requires a far more reliable way to track this information :)

Comment: then try `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Comment: well I am out of time..I think HTTP_REFERER is your best bet so far.

Comment: @Marty Thanks, this is the most helpful response so far. I am now returning the HTTP_REFERER using AMFPHP, but it seems to be returning the URL of the SWF and not of the page that the SWF is embedded on. Do you have any other suggestions? Reliability is important - no matter how complex the solution.

Comment: @user1301936 Being a game developer distributing to multiple portals myself I know it's definitely possible - Mochimedia has an analytics service that tracks the URLs and there are many games that lock features down to certain domains (for example armorgames). Just not 100% sure how it's done).